# The activities don't come with ActionBar nor the menu xmls get generated in res/menu

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, android-actionbar

I am really stumped here ... I know how to add the ActionBar and the Menu manually ,but that is not the point. When I first made my Application all activities that I created (Right click on the package New/Activity/BlankActivity) came with ActionBars enabled and Android studio generated the menu.xmls in the res/menu folder. It also added the "onCreateOptionsMenu" and "onOptionsItemSelected" in the java class automatically...But now nothing...
What do I do to make the Activities I create ,come with generated ActionBars and Menus

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: What do I do to make the Activities I create ,come with generated ActionBars and Menus

Comment: Are you using Android Studio v1.4? When I create a new project it gives me the option to set the layout file, the menu resource, etc.

Comment: Yes I am . I made a new dummy project and it only gave me the extra menu option when I first created the application and it asked me to make an activity...And every other activity i try to create gives me this http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/549/8409549K.png

Comment: Yes, that `menu_main.xml` is the file for your ActionBar menu. And the picture of the Activity clearly shows an Activity with an ActionBar. I'm not seeing the issue.

Comment: The problem is that the menu_main.xml gets generated only for the first Activity(the one that gets created with the application) and every single next Activity i try to create just gives me the Activity creation screen that i posted in the image(the one without the menu name option)

Comment: That's because the ActionBar is shared across all Activities. So the menu is the same file for every Activity, since it's always the same menu for the same ActionBar which is shown on every Activity.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio v1.4 when you are prompted to select type of your activity, select blank activity instead of empty activity....

Please note that two xml files are generated when you select blank activity so use content_main.xml to put your stuff.